# Stop text wrapping

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

On the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/4fgkj/

Here is a snippet of the HTML as it would have been too much HTML to post up here if I posted the whole thing:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <ul class="column">
            <li class="one">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">SIDE MENU</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">SIDE MENU</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">SIDE MENU</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="two">
                <ul>
                    <li class="main_content">

                        <p>content goes here</p>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will see that I have a menu and some content.  The problem is that I don't want the content to wrap around the menu.

How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: why are you putting your content in an li? `li`'s are for lists

Comment: @Pete, Probably because I misunderstood advice about html semantics from another question...

Comment: to answer your question, if you change the width of your .two and float it right, your problem will be solved: http://jsfiddle.net/4fgkj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `li` for content, it's only used for displaying lists (such as menus). 
Second - to answer your question - a structure like this might do what you want, and is quite regularly used:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
             header
    </div> 
    <div class="wrapright">       
        <div class="right">
            right
        </div>
    </div>    
        <div class="left">
            left
        </div> 
        <div class="footer">
            footer
        </div>     
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.header{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4
}
.wrapright{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #cfcfcf
}
.right{
   margin-left: 220px;
   background-color: #afeeee;
   height: 200px;
}
.left{
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: -100%;
   background-color: #98fb98;
   height: 200px;
}
.footer{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
body {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

---

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HUbjv/)

---

Of course, you'll have to adjust the CSS to change background colour, padding,... and the HTML to adjust the content. But I think you'll be able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't tell it to wrap around... in :

```
#main .column .one {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 0px;
    float:left;
}
```

just remove the line

```
float:left;
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I want the main text to be on the right of the menu, but I don't want it to go under the menu.  Removing `float:left` makes all of the text go under the menu.

Comment: oh ok, indeed... then the best would be to put 2 div elements side by side, the first to contain your menu, the second to contain your text...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `min-height` to your css rules (`#main .column .one`). If you set it, your content will be right the menu, but will not be wrapped around it.

```
#main .column .one {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 0px;
    float:left;
    min-height:600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add this to your styles:

```
.main_content {overflow: hidden;}
```

However, I must say, using a `ul` for page layout like that is not a good idea. Semantically, your page content is not an unordered list.